# How to recover blockchain.info legacy wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I gathered that Blockchain switched to new-style HD wallets sometime in 2016. At that time they used to have logins for both new-style and legacy wallet IDs. They no longer support logins with legacy wallet ID.

I have:

1. legacy username
2. 15-word mnemonic
3. passphrase (verified, 15-word mnemonic results in this passphrase using [this tool](https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password)).

Here is the message I get:

> Password: superSecret123
>
> Password not working? It may have been changed since the time the
>   wallet was created or a browser error. Please contact the help desk
>   with your wallet recover mnemonic to have a backup restored from an
>   earlier date.
>
> Locked out due to two factor authentication? Please use the following
>   link to reset two factor authentication: Two Factor Authentication
>   Reset

Blockchain's wallet id/password [recovery tools](https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/help) do not work with legacy wallets (this makes sense: how can they send me the new wallet ID if I never had one?)

Their "industry leading" support is not responding. I bet they are swamped with requests like this. Is there a way to convert legacy wallet to new-style wallet given the information listed above?

Comment: Didn't you recovered a wallet-id and a passphrase at step 3.?

Comment: @Chak: no. I was able to verify that 15-word mnemonic produces the passphrase that I already have. It does not produce wallet ID.

Comment: That's weird, it is supposed to recover both wallet-id and passphrase. You better ask blockchain's support,

Comment: I recovered the funds. The only way to do that was by talking to blockchain.info support. They were able to provide the new-style HD wallet-ID. @Chak, I am not sure why you and others think this question is a duplicate, as it deals with wallet-ID recovery given blockchain.info's legacy mnemonic.